# How do I restore a WPF application from tray icon instead of turning it on by clicking a shortcut on the desktop?

Tags: c#

Consider:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    private Mutex myMutex;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs theArgs)
    {
        bool aIsNewInstance = false;
        myMutex = new Mutex(true, "Testing", out aIsNewInstance);
        if (!aIsNewInstance)
        {
            App.Current.Shutdown();
            Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
            {
                if (process.Id != current.Id)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = FindWindow(null, "Testing");
                    App.Current.Shutdown();
                    ShowWindow(pointer, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I prevent the second copy of my application to be launched when I double-click the icon and instead to have the already-running and minimized into tray application to show the window?

Answer (score 0):

Just activate your window when the user click on your Tray-Icon.

Activating window: `myWindowToFront.Activate();`

WPF-Tray-Icon: [WPF NotifyIcon](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aacbc77c-4ef6-456f-80b7-1f157c2909f7/) (Very nice stuff)